# How to print query results in Python including column names

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

When printing PostgreSQL query results I  only see the result values, I would like to see the column name along with the result values

```
 postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT epic,timestamp FROM market_data_historic s1 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM market_data_historic s2 WHERE s1.epic = s2.epic)"
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    # Close the connection
    result=(cursor.fetchall())
    for row in result:
        print (row)
```

This is the result I get:

```
('CC.D.LCO.USS.IP', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 22, 0))
('IX.D.DAX.DAILY.IP', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 23, 4, 0))
('KB.D.ELECTY.DAILY.IP', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 16, 0))
('CS.D.ALUMINIUM.TODAY.IP', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 23, 1, 0))
('CS.D.NZDCAD.TODAY.IP', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 21, 0))
('CS.D.CADCNH.TODAY.IP', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 16, 8, 0))
```

How can I get it to be like this:

```
(epic:'CC.D.LCO.USS.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 22, 0))
(epic:'IX.D.DAX.DAILY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 23, 4, 0))
(epic:'KB.D.ELECTY.DAILY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 16, 0))
(epic:'CS.D.ALUMINIUM.TODAY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 23, 1, 0))
(epic:'CS.D.NZDCAD.TODAY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 21, 0))
(epic:'CS.D.CADCNH.TODAY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 16, 8, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [cursor.description](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description) attribute to retrieve column names and convert results to dictionaries:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
for row in result:
    print (dict(zip(columns, row)))
```

Alternatively, you can use [Real dictionary cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=range#real-dictionary-cursor) or [Named tuple cursor.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=range#namedtuple-cursor)

See also [DictCursor vs RealDictCursor.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228841/1995738)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`description`](/boot/initramfs-5.4.14-100.fc30.x86_64.img) attribute of `cursor`:

> Read-only attribute describing the result of a query. It is a sequence of `Column` instances, each one describing one result column in order. The attribute is `None` for operations that do not return rows or if the cursor has not had an operation invoked via the `execute*()` methods yet.
>
> For compatibility with the DB-API, every object can be unpacked as a 7-items sequence: the attributes retuned this way are the following. For further details and other attributes available check the `Column` documentation.
>
> - `name`: the name of the column returned.
> - `type_code`: the PostgreSQL OID of the column.
> - `display_size`: the actual length of the column in bytes.
> - `internal_size`: the size in bytes of the column associated to this column on the server.
> - `precision`: total number of significant digits in columns of type `NUMERIC`. `None` for other types.
> - `scale`: count of decimal digits in the fractional part in columns of type `NUMERIC`. `None` for other types.
> - `null_ok`: always `None` as not easy to retrieve from the libpq.