# Convert Postgres query results to a json object via Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm relatively inexperienced with JSON and Postgres so please bear with me and point out any daft mistakes I've made.  I have an AWS Lambda that queries a Postgres database via an fstring query and I need to return the results of that query as a JSON object via an API for a front end.

Ive got hardcoded values for now as, eventually, the lambda will accept a json payload detailing table name and search field plus value:

```py
import psycopg2, logging   
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=AWS_HOST,
                                database="postgres",
                                user="admin",
                                port="5432",
                                password="********")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        table_to_select = 'fps.tbl_contractor'
        record_to_select = 101
        sql_select_query = f'Select * from {table_to_select} where contractor_id = {record_to_select}'
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
        print("Query results: ", cursor.fetchall())
        connection.commit()
        count = cursor.rowcount
        print(count, "Record selected successfully ")
        
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error in Select operation", error)
        return {"Error": "Record not found or does not exist!"}, 404
    
    finally:
        # closing database connection.
        if connection is not None:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Ive been looking at SELECT to_json via the postgres documentation and other questions on Stack Overflow but am still a little lost.

Any help is appreciated!  Postgres version is 13.4

Comment: See [DictCursor vs RealDictCursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228841/1995738) for ready-to-use examples.

Comment: 1) **Do not** use `f` strings to build a query. See [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). In particular: " Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint." `f` strings are a form of string interpolation. 2) Follow @klin's advice and return the results as `list` of `dict`. Then use Python `json` module to turn them into JSON. Beware there will be issues with type e.g. timestamp, numeric as examples.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm curious - assuming there is no subsequent manipulation of the result, do you see any particular benefit in doing the JSON encoding in the Python layer, as opposed to something like `SELECT json_agg(tbl)::text from tbl`? (I'll grant doing it in the Python layer is probably more futureproof).

Comment: @snakecharmerb.  1) `json_agg` creates an  JSON array and the OP is looking for a JSON object. 2) `::text` is not needed as `psycopg2` does [json](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) adaption 3) I could see something like `select  row_to_json(tbl.*) from tbl;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm sorry, perhaps I was being unclear.  The essence of my question was, if I can generate a JSON string in Postgres, why would I do the JSON-encoding in the Python layer which might be slower ? (The purpose of `::text` would be precisely to avoid having Python convert the JSON to Python objects, only to encode it back to JSON immediately).

Comment: I see/saw your point. It comes down to what this: '...return the results of that query as a JSON object via an API' means? If the API can just pass a JSON string through then I see your point. If the API is Python based and is looking for Python objects then the conversion is needed, if nowhere else then passing Python objects directly from the query e.g. a list of dicts. for conversion by the API code itself.